# VBA skip if wrong variable type

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping through a list of items most of which are numbers but occasionally I get a string.

I would like to skip the strings and go to the next row without breaking the loop.
I am defining the numbers as doubles so the strings give me a type mismatch errror.
I think I should be using some sort of IF test but am unsure how to tell VBA to skip the 'wrong' variables.

I have tried using variants to avoid the error but can't find an IF test to tell them apart.

Comment: Please, edit your question and show us the code you use, specifying where the error appears. Even if it may be obvious... Basically, you should check if the variable looks like a number (`isNumeric`).

Comment: Have you tried using the [IsNumeric function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function)?

Comment: Is numeric is probably not the right solution. I would point the OP to the typename 
function

Comment: @freeflow I (only) suppose that all the used range is formatted in the same way and only some cells contains strings. In such a case, declaring the variables `As Double`, `IsNumeric` should be enough. Otherwise, if the range is formatted as `Text`, all numbers from the range will be skipped, if `TypeName` returns `String`.

Comment: Thank you using variants and IsNumeric worked for me!

Comment: Just in case you have formatted certain cells as Text, you would check this *only* via the `.NumberFormat` property (here e.g. `"@"`), as `IsNumeric`, `TypeName` (c.f. `VarType`) would identify a string with valid numeric input as e.g. `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get only *explicit numbers* **excluding** thereby also *any* **text-formatted numbers** (`NumberFormat = "@"`), which would be interpreted as `Double` anyway, you might code as follows checking for the variable type (`VarType`) as well as for the `NumberFormat`:

```
Sub ExplicitNumbersOnly()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Tabelle1.Range("A2:A10")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        Dim currCell As Range: Set currCell = rng.Cells(i, 1)
        If VarType(currCell) = vbDouble And currCell.NumberFormat <> "@" Then
            Debug.Print "OK:", currCell.Value
            '... do something
            '...
        Else
            'Debug.Print "Omitted: " & currCell.Address
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tiny example of explicitly testing each value to see if it is "double compatible":

```
Sub NumCk()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, v As Variant, d As Double
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        On Error Resume Next
            d = CDbl(v)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                r.Offset(0, 1) = d / 2
            Else
                Err.Number = 0
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next r
            
End Sub
```

It will reject a text value like "hello world" but accept a value like "1.2" as a text string.

Comment: Wouldn't skip cells being formatted explicitly as text, though - see my comment to OP.

Comment: @T.M.  You are correct!  My code would accept both true numbers as well as text that can be interpreted as a double.

Comment: @T.M.  I edittined the answer to give a better explanation.

Comment: Fyi might want to see my answer where I include a double check (vartype + numberformat).

Comment: @T.M.  An interesting take on the issue.  I upvoted your approach because it handles a different kind of "non-number"